# SD card wont work in linux, but in uboot does. Error -84 EILSEQ

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, sd-card, mmc

ARMv7, Kernel 4.0, dw_mmc driver

CMD18 Multiblockread and CMD17 Single block read are failing during driver initialisation sequence.. I can not figure out, what the problem is. These CMDs return with -84, which means:

```
 * EILSEQ       Basic format problem with the received or sent data
 *              (e.g. CRC check failed, incorrect opcode in response
 *              or bad end bit)
```

I am able to load files from the sd card in uboot and most of the CMDs are also working in the dw_mmc driver as you can see below.

Clock is set to 25MHz, tested are two different sd cards (=same result).

```
    device: 'mmc.0': device_add
bus: 'platform': add device mmc.0
bus: 'mmc': registered
device class 'mmc_host': registering
Driver 'mmcblk' needs updating - please use bus_type methods
bus: 'mmc': add driver mmcblk
bus: 'platform': add driver dw_mmc
bus: 'platform': add driver dwmmc_adi
bus: 'platform': driver_probe_device: matched device mmc.0 with driver dwmmc_adi
bus: 'platform': really_probe: probing driver dwmmc_adi with device mmc.0
pinctrl-adi2 pinctrl-adi2.0: found group selector 21 for mmc0grp
pinctrl-adi2 pinctrl-adi2.0: request pin 76 (PE12) for mmc.0
pinctrl-adi2 pinctrl-adi2.0: request pin 77 (PE13) for mmc.0
pinctrl-adi2 pinctrl-adi2.0: request pin 78 (PE14) for mmc.0
pinctrl-adi2 pinctrl-adi2.0: request pin 79 (PE15) for mmc.0
pinctrl-adi2 pinctrl-adi2.0: request pin 80 (PF0) for mmc.0
pinctrl-adi2 pinctrl-adi2.0: request pin 81 (PF1) for mmc.0
pinctrl-adi2 pinctrl-adi2.0: request pin 82 (PF2) for mmc.0
pinctrl-adi2 pinctrl-adi2.0: request pin 83 (PF3) for mmc.0
pinctrl-adi2 pinctrl-adi2.0: request pin 87 (PF7) for mmc.0
pinctrl-adi2 pinctrl-adi2.0: request pin 84 (PF4) for mmc.0
pinctrl-adi2 pinctrl-adi2.0: request pin 44 (PC12) for mmc.0
dwmmc_adi mmc.0: num-slots property not found, assuming 1 slot is available
dwmmc_adi mmc.0: obtain a copy of previously claimed pinctrl
dwmmc_adi mmc.0: IDMAC supports 32-bit address mode.
dwmmc_adi mmc.0: Using internal DMA controller.
dwmmc_adi mmc.0: Version ID is 270a
dwmmc_adi mmc.0: DW MMC controller at irq 73, 32 bit host data width, 1024 deep fifo
dwmmc_adi mmc.0: No vmmc regulator found
dwmmc_adi mmc.0: No vqmmc regulator found
dwmmc_adi mmc.0: GPIO lookup for consumer wp
dwmmc_adi mmc.0: using device tree for GPIO lookup
of_get_named_gpiod_flags: can't parse 'wp-gpios' property of node '/scb/mmc@0x31010000[0]'
of_get_named_gpiod_flags: can't parse 'wp-gpio' property of node '/scb/mmc@0x31010000[0]'
dwmmc_adi mmc.0: using lookup tables for GPIO lookup
dwmmc_adi mmc.0: lookup for GPIO wp failed
mmc_host mmc0: card is non-removable.
device: 'mmc0': device_add
mmc0: clock 0Hz busmode 2 powermode 1 cs 0 Vdd 21 width 0 timing 0
dwmmc_adi mmc.0: Initial signal voltage of 3.3v
mmc0: clock 400000Hz busmode 2 powermode 2 cs 0 Vdd 21 width 0 timing 0
dwmmc_adi mmc.0: 1 slots initialized
driver: 'dwmmc_adi': driver_bound: bound to device 'mmc.0'
bus: 'platform': really_probe: bound device mmc.0 to driver dwmmc_adi
mmc0: mmc_rescan_try_freq: trying to init card at 400000 Hz
mmc0: starting CMD52 arg 00000c00 flags 00000195
mmc0: req done (CMD52): -110: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
mmc0: starting CMD52 arg 80000c08 flags 00000195
mmc0: req done (CMD52): -110: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
mmc0: clock 400000Hz busmode 2 powermode 2 cs 1 Vdd 21 width 0 timing 0
mmc0: starting CMD0 arg 00000000 flags 000000c0
mmc0: req done (CMD0): 0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
mmc0: clock 400000Hz busmode 2 powermode 2 cs 0 Vdd 21 width 0 timing 0
mmc0: starting CMD8 arg 000001aa flags 000002f5
mmc0: req done (CMD8): 0: 000001aa 00000000 00000000 00000000
mmc0: starting CMD5 arg 00000000 flags 000002e1
mmc0: req failed (CMD5): -110, retrying...
mmc0: req failed (CMD5): -110, retrying...
mmc0: req failed (CMD5): -110, retrying...
mmc0: req done (CMD5): -110: 000001aa 00000000 00000000 00000000
mmc0: starting CMD55 arg 00000000 flags 000000f5
mmc0: req done (CMD55): 0: 00400120 00000000 00000000 00000000
mmc0: starting CMD41 arg 00000000 flags 000000e1
mmc0: req done (CMD41): 0: 00ff8000 00000000 00000000 00000000
mmc0: clock 400000Hz busmode 2 powermode 2 cs 1 Vdd 21 width 0 timing 0
mmc0: starting CMD0 arg 00000000 flags 000000c0
mmc0: req done (CMD0): 0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
mmc0: clock 400000Hz busmode 2 powermode 2 cs 0 Vdd 21 width 0 timing 0
mmc0: starting CMD8 arg 000001aa flags 000002f5
mmc0: req done (CMD8): 0: 000001aa 00000000 00000000 00000000
mmc0: starting CMD55 arg 00000000 flags 000000f5
mmc0: req done (CMD55): 0: 00000120 00000000 00000000 00000000
mmc0: starting CMD41 arg 40200000 flags 000000e1
mmc0: req done (CMD41): 0: 00ff8000 00000000 00000000 00000000
mmc0: starting CMD55 arg 00000000 flags 000000f5
mmc0: req done (CMD55): 0: 00000120 00000000 00000000 00000000
mmc0: starting CMD41 arg 40200000 flags 000000e1
mmc0: req done (CMD41): 0: 80ff8000 00000000 00000000 00000000
mmc0: starting CMD2 arg 00000000 flags 00000067
mmc0: req done (CMD2): 0: 6f000053 4d492020 10000002 8600fcd7
mmc0: starting CMD3 arg 00000000 flags 00000075
mmc0: req done (CMD3): 0: b3680520 00000000 00000000 00000000
mmc0: starting CMD9 arg b3680000 flags 00000007
mmc0: req done (CMD9): 0: 00000032 5f5a83b5 edb7ffbf 968000d9
mmc0: starting CMD7 arg b3680000 flags 00000015
mmc0: req done (CMD7): 0: 00000700 00000000 00000000 00000000
mmc0: starting CMD55 arg b3680000 flags 00000095
mmc0: req done (CMD55): 0: 00000920 00000000 00000000 00000000
mmc0: starting CMD51 arg 00000000 flags 000000b5
mmc0:     blksz 8 blocks 1 flags 00000200 tsac 100 ms nsac 0
mmc0: req done (CMD51): 0: 00000920 00000000 00000000 00000000
mmc0:     8 bytes transferred: 0
mmc0: starting CMD55 arg b3680000 flags 00000095
mmc0: req done (CMD55): 0: 00000920 00000000 00000000 00000000
mmc0: starting CMD13 arg 00000000 flags 000001b5
mmc0:     blksz 64 blocks 1 flags 00000200 tsac 100 ms nsac 0
mmc0: req done (CMD13): 0: 00000920 00000000 00000000 00000000
mmc0:     64 bytes transferred: 0
mmc0: starting CMD6 arg 00fffff0 flags 000000b5
mmc0:     blksz 64 blocks 1 flags 00000200 tsac 100 ms nsac 0
mmc0: req done (CMD6): 0: 00000900 00000000 00000000 00000000
mmc0:     64 bytes transferred: 0
mmc_host mmc0: card is read-write
mmc0: clock 25000000Hz busmode 2 powermode 2 cs 0 Vdd 21 width 0 timing 0
mmc_host mmc0: Bus speed (slot 0) = 75000000Hz (slot req 25000000Hz, actual 18750000HZ div = 2)
mmc0: starting CMD55 arg b3680000 flags 00000095
mmc0: req done (CMD55): 0: 00000920 00000000 00000000 00000000
mmc0: starting CMD6 arg 00000002 flags 00000015
mmc0: req done (CMD6): 0: 00000920 00000000 00000000 00000000
mmc0: clock 25000000Hz busmode 2 powermode 2 cs 0 Vdd 21 width 2 timing 0
mmc0: new SD card at address b368
device: 'mmc0:b368': device_add
bus: 'mmc': add device mmc0:b368
bus: 'mmc': driver_probe_device: matched device mmc0:b368 with driver mmcblk
bus: 'mmc': really_probe: probing driver mmcblk with device mmc0:b368
mmcblk mmc0:b368: no of_node; not parsing pinctrl DT
mmcblk mmc0:b368: no default pinctrl state
mmcblk0: mmc0:b368 SMI   1.85 GiB 
device: 'mmcblk0': device_add
mmc0: starting CMD18 arg 00000000 flags 000000b5
mmc0:     blksz 512 blocks 8 flags 00000200 tsac 100 ms nsac 0
mmc0:     CMD12 arg 00000000 flags 00000095
dwmmc_adi mmc.0: data error, status 0x00008088
mmc0: req done (CMD18): 0: 00000900 00000000 00000000 00000000
mmc0:     0 bytes transferred: -84
mmc0:     (CMD12): 0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
mmc0: starting CMD13 arg b3680000 flags 00000195
mmc0: req done (CMD13): 0: 00000900 00000000 00000000 00000000
mmcblk0: error -84 transferring data, sector 0, nr 8, cmd response 0x900, card status 0x0
mmc0: clock 0Hz busmode 2 powermode 0 cs 0 Vdd 0 width 0 timing 0
mmc0: clock 0Hz busmode 2 powermode 1 cs 0 Vdd 21 width 0 timing 0
dwmmc_adi mmc.0: Initial signal voltage of 3.3v
mmc0: clock 400000Hz busmode 2 powermode 2 cs 0 Vdd 21 width 0 timing 0
mmc_host mmc0: Bus speed (slot 0) = 75000000Hz (slot req 400000Hz, actual 398936HZ div = 94)
mmc0: clock 400000Hz busmode 2 powermode 2 cs 1 Vdd 21 width 0 timing 0
mmc0: starting CMD0 arg 00000000 flags 000000c0
mmc0: req done (CMD0): 0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
mmc0: clock 400000Hz busmode 2 powermode 2 cs 0 Vdd 21 width 0 timing 0
mmc0: starting CMD8 arg 000001aa flags 000002f5
mmc0: req done (CMD8): 0: 000001aa 00000000 00000000 00000000
mmc0: starting CMD55 arg 00000000 flags 000000f5
mmc0: req done (CMD55): 0: 00000120 00000000 00000000 00000000
mmc0: starting CMD41 arg 40200000 flags 000000e1
mmc0: req done (CMD41): 0: 00ff8000 00000000 00000000 00000000
mmc0: starting CMD55 arg 00000000 flags 000000f5
mmc0: req done (CMD55): 0: 00000120 00000000 00000000 00000000
mmc0: starting CMD41 arg 40200000 flags 000000e1
mmc0: req done (CMD41): 0: 80ff8000 00000000 00000000 00000000
mmc0: starting CMD2 arg 00000000 flags 00000067
mmc0: req done (CMD2): 0: 6f000053 4d492020 10000002 8600fcd7
mmc0: starting CMD3 arg 00000000 flags 00000075
mmc0: req done (CMD3): 0: b3680520 00000000 00000000 00000000
mmc0: starting CMD7 arg b3680000 flags 00000015
mmc0: req done (CMD7): 0: 00000700 00000000 00000000 00000000
mmc0: clock 25000000Hz busmode 2 powermode 2 cs 0 Vdd 21 width 0 timing 0
mmc_host mmc0: Bus speed (slot 0) = 75000000Hz (slot req 25000000Hz, actual 18750000HZ div = 2)
mmc0: starting CMD55 arg b3680000 flags 00000095
mmc0: req done (CMD55): 0: 00000920 00000000 00000000 00000000
mmc0: starting CMD6 arg 00000002 flags 00000015
mmc0: req done (CMD6): 0: 00000920 00000000 00000000 00000000
mmc0: clock 25000000Hz busmode 2 powermode 2 cs 0 Vdd 21 width 2 timing 0
mmc0: tried to reset card
mmc0: starting CMD18 arg 00000000 flags 000000b5
mmc0:     blksz 512 blocks 8 flags 00000200 tsac 100 ms nsac 0
mmc0:     CMD12 arg 00000000 flags 00000095
dwmmc_adi mmc.0: data error, status 0x00008088
mmc0: req done (CMD18): 0: 00000900 00000000 00000000 00000000
mmc0:     0 bytes transferred: -84
mmc0:     (CMD12): 0: 00000b00 00000000 00000000 00000000
mmc0: starting CMD13 arg b3680000 flags 00000195
mmc0: req done (CMD13): 0: 00000900 00000000 00000000 00000000
mmcblk0: error -84 transferring data, sector 0, nr 8, cmd response 0x900, card status 0xb00
mmcblk0: retrying using single block read
mmc0: starting CMD17 arg 00000000 flags 000000b5
mmc0:     blksz 512 blocks 1 flags 00000200 tsac 100 ms nsac 0
dwmmc_adi mmc.0: data error, status 0x00008088
mmc0: req done (CMD17): 0: 00000900 00000000 00000000 00000000
mmc0:     0 bytes transferred: -84
mmc0: starting CMD13 arg b3680000 flags 00000195
mmc0: req done (CMD13): 0: 00000900 00000000 00000000 00000000
mmcblk0: error -84 transferring data, sector 0, nr 8, cmd response 0x900, card status 0x0
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 0
mmc0: starting CMD17 arg 00000200 flags 000000b5
mmc0:     blksz 512 blocks 1 flags 00000200 tsac 100 ms nsac 0
dwmmc_adi mmc.0: data error, status 0x00008088
mmc0: req done (CMD17): 0: 00000900 00000000 00000000 00000000
mmc0:     0 bytes transferred: -84
mmc0: starting CMD13 arg b3680000 flags 00000195
mmc0: req done (CMD13): 0: 00000900 00000000 00000000 00000000
mmcblk0: error -84 transferring data, sector 1, nr 7, cmd response 0x900, card status 0x0
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 1
mmc0: starting CMD17 arg 00000400 flags 000000b5
mmc0:     blksz 512 blocks 1 flags 00000200 tsac 100 ms nsac 0
dwmmc_adi mmc.0: data error, status 0x00008088
mmc0: req done (CMD17): 0: 00000900 00000000 00000000 00000000
mmc0:     0 bytes transferred: -84
mmc0: starting CMD13 arg b3680000 flags 00000195
mmc0: req done (CMD13): 0: 00000900 00000000 00000000 00000000
mmcblk0: error -84 transferring data, sector 2, nr 6, cmd response 0x900, card status 0x0
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 2
mmc0: starting CMD17 arg 00000600 flags 000000b5
mmc0:     blksz 512 blocks 1 flags 00000200 tsac 100 ms nsac 0
dwmmc_adi mmc.0: data error, status 0x00008088
mmc0: req done (CMD17): 0: 00000900 00000000 00000000 00000000
mmc0:     0 bytes transferred: -84
mmc0: starting CMD13 arg b3680000 flags 00000195
mmc0: req done (CMD13): 0: 00000900 00000000 00000000 00000000
mmcblk0: error -84 transferring data, sector 3, nr 5, cmd response 0x900, card status 0x0
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 3
mmc0: starting CMD17 arg 00000800 flags 000000b5
mmc0:     blksz 512 blocks 1 flags 00000200 tsac 100 ms nsac 0
dwmmc_adi mmc.0: data error, status 0x00008088
mmc0: req done (CMD17): 0: 00000900 00000000 00000000 00000000
mmc0:     0 bytes transferred: -84
mmc0: starting CMD13 arg b3680000 flags 00000195
mmc0: req done (CMD13): 0: 00000900 00000000 00000000 00000000
mmcblk0: error -84 transferring data, sector 4, nr 4, cmd response 0x900, card status 0x0
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 4
mmc0: starting CMD17 arg 00000a00 flags 000000b5
mmc0:     blksz 512 blocks 1 flags 00000200 tsac 100 ms nsac 0
dwmmc_adi mmc.0: data error, status 0x00008088
mmc0: req done (CMD17): 0: 00000900 00000000 00000000 00000000
mmc0:     0 bytes transferred: -84
mmc0: starting CMD13 arg b3680000 flags 00000195
mmc0: req done (CMD13): 0: 00000900 00000000 00000000 00000000
mmcblk0: error -84 transferring data, sector 5, nr 3, cmd response 0x900, card status 0x0
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 5
mmc0: starting CMD17 arg 00000c00 flags 000000b5
mmc0:     blksz 512 blocks 1 flags 00000200 tsac 100 ms nsac 0
dwmmc_adi mmc.0: data error, status 0x00008088
mmc0: req done (CMD17): 0: 00000900 00000000 00000000 00000000
mmc0:     0 bytes transferred: -84
mmc0: starting CMD13 arg b3680000 flags 00000195
mmc0: req done (CMD13): 0: 00000900 00000000 00000000 00000000
mmcblk0: error -84 transferring data, sector 6, nr 2, cmd response 0x900, card status 0x0
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 6
mmc0: starting CMD17 arg 00000e00 flags 000000b5
mmc0:     blksz 512 blocks 1 flags 00000200 tsac 100 ms nsac 0
dwmmc_adi mmc.0: data error, status 0x00008088
mmc0: req done (CMD17): 0: 00000900 00000000 00000000 00000000
mmc0:     0 bytes transferred: -84
mmc0: starting CMD13 arg b3680000 flags 00000195
mmc0: req done (CMD13): 0: 00000900 00000000 00000000 00000000
mmcblk0: error -84 transferring data, sector 7, nr 1, cmd response 0x900, card status 0x0
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 7
Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk0, logical block 0, async page read
mmc0: starting CMD18 arg 00000000 flags 000000b5
mmc0:     blksz 512 blocks 8 flags 00000200 tsac 100 ms nsac 0
mmc0:     CMD12 arg 00000000 flags 00000095
dwmmc_adi mmc.0: data error, status 0x00008088
mmc0: req done (CMD18): 0: 00000900 00000000 00000000 00000000
mmc0:     0 bytes transferred: -84
mmc0:     (CMD12): 0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
mmc0: starting CMD13 arg b3680000 flags 00000195
mmc0: req done (CMD13): 0: 00000900 00000000 00000000 00000000
mmcblk0: error -84 transferring data, sector 0, nr 8, cmd response 0x900, card status 0x0
mmcblk0: retrying using single block read
mmc0: starting CMD17 arg 00000000 flags 000000b5
mmc0:     blksz 512 blocks 1 flags 00000200 tsac 100 ms nsac 0
dwmmc_adi mmc.0: data error, status 0x00008088
mmc0: req done (CMD17): 0: 00000900 00000000 00000000 00000000
mmc0:     0 bytes transferred: -84
mmc0: starting CMD13 arg b3680000 flags 00000195
mmc0: req done (CMD13): 0: 00000900 00000000 00000000 00000000
mmcblk0: error -84 transferring data, sector 0, nr 8, cmd response 0x900, card status 0x0
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 0
mmc0: starting CMD17 arg 00000200 flags 000000b5
mmc0:     blksz 512 blocks 1 flags 00000200 tsac 100 ms nsac 0
dwmmc_adi mmc.0: data error, status 0x00008088
mmc0: req done (CMD17): 0: 00000900 00000000 00000000 00000000
mmc0:     0 bytes transferred: -84
mmc0: starting CMD13 arg b3680000 flags 00000195
mmc0: req done (CMD13): 0: 00000900 00000000 00000000 00000000
mmcblk0: error -84 transferring data, sector 1, nr 7, cmd response 0x900, card status 0x0
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 1
mmc0: starting CMD17 arg 00000400 flags 000000b5
mmc0:     blksz 512 blocks 1 flags 00000200 tsac 100 ms nsac 0
dwmmc_adi mmc.0: data error, status 0x00008088
mmc0: req done (CMD17): 0: 00000900 00000000 00000000 00000000
mmc0:     0 bytes transferred: -84
mmc0: starting CMD13 arg b3680000 flags 00000195
mmc0: req done (CMD13): 0: 00000900 00000000 00000000 00000000
mmcblk0: error -84 transferring data, sector 2, nr 6, cmd response 0x900, card status 0x0
mmc0: starting CMD17 arg 00000600 flags 000000b5
mmc0:     blksz 512 blocks 1 flags 00000200 tsac 100 ms nsac 0
dwmmc_adi mmc.0: data error, status 0x00008088
mmc0: req done (CMD17): 0: 00000900 00000000 00000000 00000000
mmc0:     0 bytes transferred: -84
mmc0: starting CMD13 arg b3680000 flags 00000195
mmc0: req done (CMD13): 0: 00000900 00000000 00000000 00000000
mmcblk0: error -84 transferring data, sector 3, nr 5, cmd response 0x900, card status 0x0
mmc0: starting CMD17 arg 00000800 flags 000000b5
mmc0:     blksz 512 blocks 1 flags 00000200 tsac 100 ms nsac 0
dwmmc_adi mmc.0: data error, status 0x00008088
mmc0: req done (CMD17): 0: 00000900 00000000 00000000 00000000
mmc0:     0 bytes transferred: -84
mmc0: starting CMD13 arg b3680000 flags 00000195
mmc0: req done (CMD13): 0: 00000900 00000000 00000000 00000000
mmcblk0: error -84 transferring data, sector 4, nr 4, cmd response 0x900, card status 0x0
mmc0: starting CMD17 arg 00000a00 flags 000000b5
mmc0:     blksz 512 blocks 1 flags 00000200 tsac 100 ms nsac 0
dwmmc_adi mmc.0: data error, status 0x00008088
mmc0: req done (CMD17): 0: 00000900 00000000 00000000 00000000
mmc0:     0 bytes transferred: -84
mmc0: starting CMD13 arg b3680000 flags 00000195
mmc0: req done (CMD13): 0: 00000900 00000000 00000000 00000000
mmcblk0: error -84 transferring data, sector 5, nr 3, cmd response 0x900, card status 0x0
mmc0: starting CMD17 arg 00000c00 flags 000000b5
mmc0:     blksz 512 blocks 1 flags 00000200 tsac 100 ms nsac 0
dwmmc_adi mmc.0: data error, status 0x00008088
mmc0: req done (CMD17): 0: 00000900 00000000 00000000 00000000
mmc0:     0 bytes transferred: -84
mmc0: starting CMD13 arg b3680000 flags 00000195
mmc0: req done (CMD13): 0: 00000900 00000000 00000000 00000000
mmcblk0: error -84 transferring data, sector 6, nr 2, cmd response 0x900, card status 0x0
mmc0: starting CMD17 arg 00000e00 flags 000000b5
mmc0:     blksz 512 blocks 1 flags 00000200 tsac 100 ms nsac 0
dwmmc_adi mmc.0: data error, status 0x00008088
mmc0: req done (CMD17): 0: 00000900 00000000 00000000 00000000
mmc0:     0 bytes transferred: -84
mmc0: starting CMD13 arg b3680000 flags 00000195
mmc0: req done (CMD13): 0: 00000900 00000000 00000000 00000000
mmcblk0: error -84 transferring data, sector 7, nr 1, cmd response 0x900, card status 0x0
Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk0, logical block 0, async page read
 mmcblk0: unable to read partition table
driver: 'mmcblk': driver_bound: bound to device 'mmc0:b368'
bus: 'mmc': really_probe: bound device mmc0:b368 to driver mmcblk
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mmc0: starting CMD18 arg 00000000 flags 000000b5
mmc0:     blksz 512 blocks 8 flags 00000200 tsac 100 ms nsac 0
mmc0:     CMD12 arg 00000000 flags 00000095
dwmmc_adi mmc.0: data error, status 0x00008088
```

Status `0x8088` indecates CRC and End-Bit-Error (EBE). Thus, I came across it was a HW issue, caused of bad connection (resistance). Checking the connection solved the error.